# A Multi-Sport Tournament for 8 Teams

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to organize a tournament with 8 teams. Each team will play 4 games. The catch is no team can play the same team twice and no team can play the same sport twice.

Help pls

Comment: How many total sports are there?

Comment: Consider changing the title: A round-robin tournament is one where each participant meets each other once. What you're asking for is something else.

Comment: A similar problem about [12 teams and 6 sports](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893396/can-12-teams-in-6-disciplines-play-6-rounds-without-repetition) was recently solved.

Answer (score 2):

The teams are $A, B,.. G, H$. The match-ups are denoted by the the lines/connections (edges) drawn between the teams (vertices). The four hideous colours - Green, Blue, Yellow and Purple - represent the four sports. Should be easy to interpret.

There are no multi-edges and hence no teams play each other twice. Each vertex has exactly four distinct edges and hence each team plays exactly four distinct sports i.e. no team plays the same sport twice.

[image]

Comment: Though quite simple, great interpretation and use of graph theory.

Comment: With a little effort it can be seen that 4 games in different sports for all 8 teams can be scheduled "in parallel" at four times for this tournament.  E.g. A-B-green, C-G-purple, D-F-yellow, and E-H-blue in the time slot; then rotate these edges a quarter turn at a time to obtain the other matchups for three more time slots.