# 8 teams and X amount of games, Need to play each game and each team

Tags: combinatorics

I'm planning an event with 8 teams and an undecided amount of games. How many games would I need, and what would the set up look like, if each team plays EVERY other team only once, and plays EVERY game only once. So they can't play the same game twice, and they can't play against the same team twice. Thanks.

Comment: You may use the fact that the complete graph on 8 vertices is 1-factorizable.

Comment: What do you mean complete graph on 8 vertices? Could you draw a picture please? I'm not well versed in math vocabulary.

Comment: Are you well-versed in Google, Michael? What happens when you type in "complete graph"?

Comment: Are you still here? Do you have any more questions about the answer that was posted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: A duplicate Question is:  [A Multi-Sport Tournament for 8 Teams](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906179/a-multi-sport-tournament-for-8-teams)

Answer (score 2):

Let the teams be denoted by $1,2,\dots,8$.

Round 1: 18, 27, 36, 45.

Round 2: 78, 16, 25, 34

Round 3: 68, 75, 14, 23

Round 4: 58, 64, 73, 12

Round 5: 48, 53, 62, 71

Round 6: 38, 42, 51, 67

Round 7: 28, 31, 47, 56

This is a fair way to schedule because at the end of each round each team will have played the same amount of games. This was obtained as a special case of the turning trick explained [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54715.html).

Comment: This is helpful, but I need each team to play each game once and only once as well.

Comment: @Michael: What do you mean? Each team is playing against each other only once above. For example teams 1 and 8 play together in round 1 and never again. Could you give an example to clarify what you want?

Comment: So, Michael, in Round 1, they all play Game 1; in Round 2, Game 2; and so on. But perhaps you have another restriction you have forgotten to tell us about.

Comment: For example, one might add a restriction that teams are paired in *distinct* games in each Round.  For example, one pair plays soccer, one baseball, one volleyball, etc. and no two teams in a round compete at the same sport except against one another.