# multi-game round robin tournament algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Each year I am part of a group that hosts a "Lawn Game Olympics." 6 different lawn games (bocce, ladder golf, washer toss etc...) and every year a different amount of teams shows up. The first year was an unbalanced schedule and the drama that ensued was ridiculous, so i've set out to create a balanced schedule with a program that we can just punch in the amount of teams.

The issue is everyone wants to play each other, or everyone wants to play the same game the same amount of times with a great effort and playing every team.

The traditional round robin formula only works for 13 teams with 1 bye, as it just happens to rotate around 6 games. Using the technique below, its simple (with 14 being a bye, and each line being a different game)

[image: Round-robin schedule for 13 teams]

13 teams never happens, just my luck, and I cannot figure anything out for any other amount of teams. I have seemingly tried everything. The closest I've gotten is using combinatorics to generate all the matchups then try to brute force them together tracking whos played who and what etc.. but that still never works before crashing.

The ideal scenario, is every team plays each game AT LEAST twice, and every opponent at least once.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? If it is, can I get a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: There is an aspect to such tournaments that you do not explicitly cover, and that is the ability to schedule all six sports simultaneously.  Of course to get each sport twice for each team, one needs (in the 12 or 13 team cases) simply to run two round-robin schedules (possibly with different orderings of teams so that different match-ups will occur).

Comment: Are you primarily interested in cases where the number of teams exceeds 13, is below 13, or is around 13 with modest excess or deficit?

Comment: A solution for twelve teams (playing six sports in parallel/simultaneously), each team playing each sport once and meeting six different opponents in as many rounds, was detailed here in [Can 12 teams in 6 disciplines play 6 rounds without repetition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893396/can-12-teams-in-6-disciplines-play-6-rounds-without-repetition).  Of course more rounds are required if each opponent must be met at least once.

Comment: @hardmath usually we sit at 14 or 15, and 12 has happened once.  The all games simultaneously point is a good point, we'd rather have all the games playing at the same time, but if make up rounds are required on the end its not a big deal. i still get the feeling that theres not going to be any algorithm i can follow, and will have to stick to trial and error.

Comment: Hi @rob zaenglein how did you go with this one? Did you find an algorithm, or are you still manually compiling your schedule?